# How to select attribute with wildcard string-search, using PHP's SimpleXML library

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to select all nodes with an attribute that contains the word "Rock", but I'm not sure how to accomplish this with PHP's SimpleXML library.  I tried appending the asterisk (wild-card) character to the attribute value, but that didn't work.

Here is a snippet of the XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Shift-JIS"?>
    <CDs>
        <Cat Type="Rock">
            <CD>
                <Name>Elvis Prestley</Name>
                <Album>Elvis At Sun</Album>
            </CD>
            <CD>
                <Name>Elvis Prestley</Name>
                <Album>Best Of...</Album>
            </CD>
        </Cat>
        <Cat Type="RocknRoll">
            <CD>
                <Name>The Beatles</Name>
                <Album>Best of...</Album>
            </CD>
        </Cat>
        <Cat Type="JazzBlues">
            <CD>
                <Name>B.B. King</Name>
                <Album>Singin' The Blues</Album>
            </CD>
            <CD>
                <Name>B.B. King</Name>
                <Album>The Blues</Album>
            </CD>
        </Cat>
    </CDs>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

    $xml = new XMLReader();
    $xml->open("MusicCatalog.xml") or die ("can't open file");
    foreach($xml->xpath("Cat[@Type='Rock*']/@Type") as $c) {
        print($c) . PHP_EOL;
    }

?>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe for this you can use `starts-with()`:

```
$xml->xpath("Cat[starts-with(@Type,'Rock')]/@Type")
```

This [works in my demo](http://viper-7.com/ATUPGI), however I am using SimpleXML. It shouldn't matter, since I believe both SimpleXML and XMLReader use libxml underneath the hood. Also, `XMLReader::xpath()` was undefined on my test machine and I don't see it in the documentation.

Comment: That's it!  It wasn't noted in the SimpleXML documentation, but I'm glad it's there.  Thank you for your contribution and your help.  I appreciate it.